# What is the difference between configuration and conformation in stereochemistry?

Tags: stereochemistry

I understand conformation to be any spacial arrangement of atoms that can be achieved through rotation of a single bond. I understand configuration to be the disposition of atoms/groups in space. However, would a conformational isomer also be a configurational isomer since the groups are arranged differently in space?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I recommend you this webpage: http://worldofbiochemistry.blogspot.com/2012/09/conformation-vs-configuration.html.
Configuration and conformation are two concepts are often used interchangeably, but represent very different things. The conformation regards the relative spatial orientation of a portion of a molecule relative to another. Thus, it is an aspect that is not directly related to the covalent bonds that are established within the molecule, but with their possible rotation.

[image]

When we talk about rotation around covalent bonds, we are only referring to the single bonds, as they are the only ones that can suffer rotation. Basically this concept is easily understood if we think that the bounds work as an axis...

It should be noted that when we speak of different conformations, it does not necessarily involve all the covalent bonds of a molecule, it can account only for one or few of them.
 Taken together, it is possible to convert one conformation to another without **cleaving or forming chemical bonds**, simply by rotating some simple covalent bonds. ***Thermal energy at room temperature is sufficient to rotate some simple covalent bonds***.

The configuration is a concept that is related to the order by which different substituents linked to the same central atom establish covalent bonds. That means, in this case it is clearly an aspect that is a direct consequence of the covalent backbone of molecules.

[image]

To change the configuration, you **must always cleave and form new covalent bonds.**..***This costs a lot of energy!!***

In conclusion, the concept conformation encompasses portions of a molecule which are not directly linked to the same atom and do not involve the covalent backbone of the molecules, while the configuration comprehends parts of the molecule which are bound to the same atom, which means that there is a direct involvement of the covalent bounds of the molecule.

Answer (score 1):

Configuration is arrangement of atom in three dimensional space around the molecule. Here there is no free rotation of atom usually we use configuration in optical isomerism and conformation is the one which allows free rotation of single bond with in  the molecule and we use conformation to represent the biomolecule structure.

Answer (score -1):

Configuration differs from conformation by a fact that conformations are only due to the orientation of the atoms in molecule around the covalent bond considering the bond as an axis.  And changing the configuration causes the cleavage and formation of new chemical bonds.